# For every vector $w \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $Aw$ is in the span of $u$. Prove this.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am unsure how to approach this question. Given is
$$
A =  \begin{pmatrix}
  2 & -1 & 3  \\
  4 & -2 & 6  \\
  -2 & 1 & -3   
 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$
u = \begin{pmatrix}
1  \\
2 \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have to prove for every $w \in \mathbb{R}^3 $ that $Aw$ is in the span of $u$.
So far I have calculated and written $Aw$ as

$$Aw =  \begin{pmatrix}
2w_1 - w_2 + 3w_3 \\
4w_1 - 2w_2 + 6w_3 \\
-2w_1 + w_2 - 3w_3 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
And I know that
$sp(u) = \{r_1 + 2r_2 - r_3 \mid r_1 , r_2 , r_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

But I do not really know where to go from here. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$Aw = \begin{pmatrix}
2w_1 - w_2 + 3w_3 \\
4w_1 - 2w_2 + 6w_3 \\
-2w_1 + w_2 - 3w_3 
\end{pmatrix}=(2w_1-w_2+3w_3)\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
2 \\
-1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Recall that the span of a set of vectors is the set of linear combinations  of those vectors.

Answer (score 0):

The column space, upon perusal, is the span of $(1,2,-1)$.  But in general, given a linear transformation represented by a matrix (rel the standard basis), the image is the column space.